# Set gsettings in Vagrant provision script

Tags: vagrant, gnome, vagrantfile

I'm running a vagrant provisioning script and I'm trying to set the desktop background, but I can't get gsettings to take. It works fine at the command line, just not from the script. Everything else in the Vagrantfile works fine.

```
  config.vm.provision "file", source: "image.jpg", destination: "~/image.jpg"
```

I use the file provision to move the file over, and then call gsettings from the non-sudo bootstrap.sh.

```
   config.vm.provision :shell, path: "sudo-bootstrap.sh"
   config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh", privileged: false
```

In bootstrap.sh:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/vagrant/image.jpg
```

I read about there not being a [DBUS Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374520/gsettings-with-cron/19666729#19666729) bus address, but adding the line to get the PID didn't work in the provisioning script. Also found it was perhaps [missing schemas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451541/how-to-change-gnome-shell-theme-with-a-bash-script), but I don't have any schemas in .local.

Been hammering at this for a few hours now, no idea what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the accepted answer to the [DBUS Session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457016/how-to-change-gsettings-via-remote-shell/457023) question didn't work for me, the linked answer under it did, [Run DBUS](https://askubuntu.com/a/326773).

```
dbus-launch gsettings set ...
```