# How to change desktop background in Linux using Cron

Tags: linux, terminal, cron, command-line-interface, wallpaper

I found Terminal command to change desktop wallpaper:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///path/to/your/image.png
```

but this command not working in cron and other desktops like Mate. `pgrep gnome-session` approach shows nothing for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Linux belong on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ If you do ask this over there, please delete this here.

Comment: I'm voting against closing it - put your effort into answering questions instead of redirecting users to other pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gsettings with cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374520/gsettings-with-cron)

Comment: @jww, this question about programming in bash (shell) and development a cross-distro script

Answer (score 6):

You can use `dconf` to change background. Here is example of simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

WP="$(find ~+ -type f -exec mimetype {} + 2>/dev/null | awk -F': +' '{ if ($2 ~ /^image\//) print $1 }' | sort -R | tail -30 | shuf -n 1)"

dconf write /org/mate/desktop/background/picture-filename "'${WP}'"
```

You can find distro-specific key using GUI app - *dconf-editor*

But to use this script in CRON you need to set session environment variables. Command `pgrep gnome-session` doesn't work in Mint and other not Gnome desktops. To solve this problem you need to save environment variables of specific user by running command at system startup:

```
env > ~/cronenv && sed -i '/%s/d' ~/cronenv
```

now you have `cronenv` file (without substitutional vars - %s) in users home dir. Just restore them back in cron before running `dconf`:

```
*/1 7-21 * * * cd ~/Pictures && env $(cat ~/cronenv | xargs) /path/to/first/script
```

Use crontab -e to edit cron jobs for current user. All works fine!